# How to add undo functionality of up to 10 undos in c++ code

Tags: c++, vtk

I am trying to add an undo functionality as a stack and I am trying to add it to the body of this code. What I am trying to do is undo an action in the VTK GUI such that even if you drag an element from one box to another, I want to undo that with the click of a button. There are no errors because I do not know where to start.

```
auto _undo{ qto_e<QAction>("Undo") };
    _toolbar->addAction(_undo);
    _main->addToolBar(
        Qt::TopToolBarArea, _toolbar
    );
    qt_o::connect(_undo,
        &QAction::triggered,
        {
            //body goes here
        }
    );
```

Comment: You could check out the memento design pattern which is meant to address this exact type of problem.

Comment: How would I approach it?

Comment: Did you check it out? I cannot really tell you how you would do it without really knowing your code....